# What is the security impact of not using tls-remote with OpenVPN

Tags: security, vpn, openvpn

Is it a security issue not using the tls-remote option in OpenVPN? That is not verifying the server's common name. Is a MITM attack possible? Could this be an issue, especially with services like dyndns.org?

Comment: "This question meets quality standards." -- what? Also, this would likely be better suited at [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There was a message, the question would not meet the Quality Standards. So I had to tell the message board that it does.

Answer (score 1):

`tls-remote` restricts OpenVPN to connect to a machine with a specific name. This isn't a very common option, and it mostly makes sense on the client side. Usually, you will want the flexibility of accepting connections from any peer that has a key from an accepted CA (specified by the `ca` option).

If you don't perform any verification on the client side, then indeed you risk a MITM attack.